# How to access variable or variable value or variable on multiple PHP pages while continuously changing its value

Tags: php

I wanna to access in given scenario the the variable `$i` as it is an incremented varaible which change value after an order. So how can i reuse it this in any other page. Morever tell me the that how can i use any "variable/varaible last value" on multiple pages without the session. And will session update the variable value when its change , if yes than how ? and There are many methods to do that ?

```
 <?php include ('header.php'); 

    if(isset($_POST['order']))
    {
        $user_id  = $_SESSION['id'];
        $date      = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $username =$_SESSION['username'];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tborder(user_id,`date`,username) VALUES('$user_id','$date','$username')") or die(mysql_error());
        $i = mysql_insert_id();
        if($i >0)
            for($l=0;$l<count($_POST['product_id']);$l++)
            {
                $product_id = $_POST['product_id'][$l];
                $quantity   = $_POST['quantity'][$l];
                $price      = $_POST['price'][$l];
                $discount   = $_POST['discount'][$l];
                $amount     = $_POST['amount'][$l];
                $username   = $_SESSION['username'];
                $user_id    = $_SESSION['id'];


        mysql_query("INSERT INTO tborderdetail(order_id,product_id,quantity,price,discount,amount,username,user_id) VALUES('$i','$product_id','$quantity','$price','$discount','$amount','$username','$user_id')")or die(mysql_error());
                header('location:order.php');
            }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You would have to use some persistent storage, like the filesystem or a database.

Comment: @Calimero is there no solution to directly access that value ?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies!

By storing the variable value in a cookie each time the value is changed, you can use the variable on multiple pages throughout the domain.

The cookie expiration time needs to be considered though, if the value is going to be there for a whole session, then storing it in a session cookie (until the browser is closed) will be useful.

Hope it helps!

Comment: is there no other way to directly access variable or variable stored values on multiple pages ?

Comment: I fear there is not. You will need some sort of storage space from where you can save the data and access it.

Comment: will you give me one more favour ?

Comment: what will that be ?

Answer (score 0):

> how can i use any "variable/varaible last value" on multiple pages without the session.

PHP variables are "lost" between page requests, unless you store them in a session.  If you don't want to use a session to store data there are many alternatives:

- **Pass values between pages** as GET or POST variables.  Any mistake and the value is "lost" again as it's not permanently stored.  The user can see and change the value themselves.
- Store in a **cookie**.  Again the user can see and change the value themselves.
- **Relational database**, e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL.  Create a table to store and query the value as needed across pages.
- **Key-value store**, e.g. Redis, memcache.  Define a key and read/write the value as needed.

> And will session update the variable value when its change

Only if you store it in the session and update it.  Each time you set a new value in the `$_SESSION` array it'll persist across pages as long as the session is alive.

Comment: Key values will work for multiple pages? and will automatically updated ? And cookies is a btter way or not ?

Comment: Key-value stores can be set up as permanent storage.  So yes, they are for use across multiple pages.  Nothing is automatically updated, you must code it to store and update values.  The same goes for every other method of storing persistent values.